# Discrepancy when using .step command in LT Spice

Tags: transistors, ltspice, simulation

I have a transistor circuit where I wish to determine the transistor dimensions W and L, such that \$V_{out} = 1.5\text{V} \$

[image]

I have defined W and L for the two NMOS transistors. I have set L = 1u in the PMOS transistors and then I am sweeping through W to find a suitable value, such that \$V_{out}=1.5\text{V} \$. This seems to happen at \$W_p = 1.44\mu \text{m} \$ and is shown in the upper draft file.

In the second LT Spice draft I set \$W_p= 1.44\mu \text{m}\$ for the PMOS transistors and run an transient simulation to make sure I get the right thing. Which I don't. As can be seen, \$V_{out}= 855\text{mV} \$, but didn't I just see from my paramter sweep that I should get 1.5V for the output voltage?

Why do I get different results when I sweep the \$W_p \$-value, and when I perform a transient (or dc operating point) simulation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a `0.1u` step, so that line that you see in the upper graph is misleading because it's just alinear interpolation from `1.4u` to `1.5u`. That `.TRAN` result of `0.855` is right between the two values. Try a finer grain, and reduce the ends, e.g. `.step param wp 1.5u 1.6u 0.01u`.  When in doubt, <kbd>R-Click</kbd> in the waveform window and select *View > Mark Data Points* (if there aren't too many, which will result in a slow update). I'd also consider not using `.TRAN` for verification (you can see that there are numeric artefacts causing the output to not be a straight line, even if only just), instead, use `.OP`.